# Sql AVG included but getting Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am very confused as to why I am getting this error:

> "Column 'City.CityID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I have two tables: one called **City** with city info, such as id, name, etc and **another table** containing the cityid and rating (there can be many rows with the same cityid and rating).

I have a `group` by for the city, and I am simply taking the average of the rating in the RateCity table.  So why would this be failing?

```
select City.CityID, City.CityName, City.CityStateOrProvince, 
City.CityCountry, City.CityImageUri, AVG(RateCity.Rating) as AverageRating
from City
right join RateCity
on City.CityID = RateCity.CityID
group by City.CityID, RateCity.CityID
```

Comment: I tried adding it to the select but get the same error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by all non-aggregates.

```
select City.CityID
      ,City.CityName
      ,City.CityStateOrProvince
      ,City.CityCountry
      ,City.CityImageUri
      ,AVG(RateCity.Rating) as AverageRating
from City 
right join RateCity on City.CityID = RateCity.CityID
 Group by 
       City.CityID
      ,City.CityName
      ,City.CityStateOrProvince
      ,City.CityCountry
      ,City.CityImageUri
```

Another option is

```
select City.CityID
      ,City.CityName
      ,CityStateOrProvince = max(City.CityStateOrProvince)
      ,CityCountry         = max(City.CityCountry)
      ,CityImageUri        = max(City.CityImageUri)
      ,AverageRating       = AVG(RateCity.Rating) 
from City 
right join RateCity on City.CityID = RateCity.CityID
 Group by 
       City.CityID
      ,City.CityName
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the issue now.

Comment: @KateMak From my experience, it is always the small things.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can only have those columns in select clause which you have included in group by clause. Any other column can only be selected if you apply aggregate function on them.
For Ex- (correct one)

```
SELECT a,b,sum(c)
From d
GROUP BY a,b;
```

(wrong one)

```
SELECT a,b,sum(c)
FROM d
GROUP BY a;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to include all the columns in the group by that are not in an aggreate

```
SELECT City.CityID, 
       City.CityName, 
       City.CityStateOrProvince, 
       City.CityCountry, 
       City.CityImageUri, 
       AVG(RateCity.Rating) as AverageRating
FROM City
RIGHT JOIN RateCity on City.CityID = RateCity.CityID
GROUP BY City.CityID, City.CityName, City.CityStateOrProvince, 
City.CityCountry, City.CityImageUri
```